# Dagger 2 : Unbounded dependency injection

Tags: android, android-fragments, generics, dependency-injection, dagger

Lately I've been struggling with dagger, and after catching up a bit, I got stuck with generics. I have several fragments, each getting it's own presenter injected. I want to extract the injection to the BaseFragment class, without :

1: Having to call:

```
((App) getActivity().getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);
```

from every single fragment

2: registering a concrete presenter field in each fragment class

3: adding seperate inject() methods in the component for each concrete Fragment i have

My main component looks like this:

```
@AppScope
@Component(modules = {...})
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    void inject(BaseFragment<BasePresenter> baseFragment);

    void inject(FeedFragment baseFragment);

    void inject(XYZFragment xyzFragment);

...
```

I have tried adding these

```
void inject(Class<? extends BaseFragment> aClass);
```

and

```
<TPresenter extends BasePresenter> void inject(BaseFragment<TPresenter> tPresenterBaseFragment);
```

but each variant gives me the same message at compilation:

```
error: Type parameters must be bounded for members injection
```

i have looked up SO, and discovered that generics are supported since Dagger 2.0, and i searched [this](https://github.com/google/dagger/commit/2ea676a2702a48866f227988a9994e0e6649e1ce), but to no avail

my BaseFragment currently looks like this

```
public abstract class BaseFragment<TPresenter extends BasePresenter> extends Fragment implements
 BaseView {

TPresenter presenter;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ((App) getActivity().getApplication()).getComponent().inject((BaseFragment) this);
}
```

any solution or a workaround how can i accomplish having only **one** inject method for BaseFragment in the ApplicationComponent, and only **one** call for it on BaseFragment, would be greatly appreciated.